# Update the parent model on child after_save, using Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, model, mongoid

A User has many Posts and a Post belongs_to a User.  Both have a location.  I'd like to store the location for each Post and update the User location with the most recent Post location.  Is after_save the way to go?  I'm very inexperienced with Mongo DB.

**Post Model**

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :update_user_location
  field :location, :type => String

  def update_user_location
     #update user's location
  end
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :posts
  field :location, :type => String
end
```

(Please don't say to just get the most recent post location, I need to store it separately for a reason...thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, have you tried anything ? Btw This is really a Mongoid specific question, not really related to MongoDB itself.

```
def update_user_location
    self.user.location = self.location
    self.user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def update_user_location
    self._parent.location = self.location
    self._parent.save
end
```

However I think I have noticed a bug, if you parent model (User) has some before_save function, the self._parent.save is not effective... I have encountered the case twice already and could not find any explanation for it.

Alex

Comment: Alex, this was my problem exactly.  I tried changing before_save to after_validation and it worked for me.  Weird, I thought it was just me... I'm still new to mongo

Comment: yeah there is still some quirky behavior, but this is mongoid rather than mongodb I believe